# Изменить значение поля объекта через переменную (JS)

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся со сложностью, не могу понять как изменить значение поля объекта через переменную. Понимаю в чем проблема но не могу найти решение. Использование переменных необходимо, иначе будет слишком длинное обращение к полю объекта.

---

**Пример:**

```
let obj = {field1: 7};
let field1= obj.field1;
console.log(field1); // 7
field1= 8;
console.log(obj.field1) // 7, а мне нужно чтобы было 8
```

Comment: `const sobject = very_long.veeery_long; sobject.field1 = value`

Comment: Никак вы так не поменяете. Вам нужно, чтобы переменная ссылалась на тот же объект, а не на поле

Comment: Все просто объекты передаются по ссылке,примитивы копируются.Пример var a = {c:{m:7}}; var b = a.c; b.m=8; console.log(a.c)

Comment: "слишком длинное обращение к полю объекта" - что значит "слишком длинное"? На что эта "длина" влияет?

Comment: @Igor Влияет на читаемость и красоту кода, получаются длинные условия и обращения к полям объектов.

Comment: @Fakie, приведи пример, что ты считаешь _слишком длинным обращением к полю объекта_

Comment: @Александр, написанное тобой не имеет ни малейшего отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

а если вот так ?

```
let obj={field1:7};
let field2=8;
console.log(obj.field1=field2);
```

Comment: Объект с уже заданными полями

Comment: не понял что тебе не нравится?

Comment: можешь поставить так console.log(obj.field1=8);

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понял проблему..но я так предполагаю.. что ты хочешь через переменную иметь доступ к полю.

```js
let objKey = 'test'
let obj = {test:7}
obj[objKey] = 8
console.log(obj.test)
```

то есть если ты хочешь использовать значение переменной как имя поля..то переменную в квадратные скобки(как ассоциативный массив)